# Using a variable image in CSS - accessing 'image' from a user schema in mongodb

Tags: css, mongodb, image, ejs

I'm using mongodb in an app that I'm creating, and I have a user schema set up as follows:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    image: String
});
```

On the landing page, I need to display the user image but I want it to be round. I've reserved a round `div` on the landing page using CSS as follows:

```
.user-img-landing {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url("??");
    margin: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to pass the user image into the `background-image`. In my `ejs` files obviously I access it by `<%=user.image%>`, but how do I do this within a CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an inline style instead of CSS file . This way you can use the property directly in ejs .